# Redirect a pdf in sharepoint library to a different pdf file?

Tags: document-library, redirect

I am looking for a way to redirect a pdf file in a sharepoint library to a different pdf in the same library?    For example, if the old file is ABC.pdf and the new file is 123.pdf - we want external users who have linked to or bookmarked the old file ABC.pdf to be redirected to 123.pdf instead of getting a 404 error if we just delete the old file.

I found an article to redirect pdfs if they were in a directory on a website - http://moz.com/community/q/301-redirect-on-a-pdf-docx-files

but I need a technique for files within a sharepoint library.

Thank you

I have additionally found a few other ideas - but I need to do more research with regards to URL rewriting:
http://forums.iis.net/t/1199665.aspx
http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2818415

Comment: have you found any solution that works for this? I tried using the link to content document type, but the problem is that is creates a redirect page (.aspx), so the old/obsolete document link still results in 404

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem when we remodeled our site, so any bookmarks got 404. Our solution (back to SP 2007) was a) to create a list with the new and old URLs and b) custom made 404 page that redirected to the new url.

Actually, we saved all 404 to this list ( as old url) and for the first 6 months we went and fill up the new url.

I guess you can do the same: See in http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/06/17/replace-default-pagenotfounderror-aspx-with-custom-error-page-in-sharepoint-2013/ option 2.

Comment: Thank you for the reply I will take a look.  Unfortunately, from your solution, it sounds like there is not a way to redirect but instead deal with the 404.

Comment: Link to a document is another solution

Comment: Hello XristosK -I am not sure what you mean by "Link to a document is another solution"  Can you elaborate?  Thank you.

Comment: There's a content type named link to a document. You could find a solution to your problem in https://www.collaboris.com/blogs/collaboris-blog/policy-management/2013/04/03/use-a-link-to-a-document-in-place-of-an-real-document-in-sharepoint#.VAc87mPezEw

Answer (score 0):

I have trouble understanding this...

"I am looking for a way to redirect a pdf file in a sharepoint library to a different pdf **in the same library**?"

If it is in the same library anyway, wouldn't you be able to just rename ABC.pdf to like ABC-OLD.pdf and rename 123.pdf to ABC.pdf? Granted it is a lot of work, I would tend to think it should preserve all the links just fine.

As a matter of fact, I did something similar on a library level at one time, and took the effort to make sure they links translate even though we switch libraries. I just renamed the old library a different name and gave the new library the name the original library had and retained the original folder structure.